# Merge two arrays into one continually gives me error in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

for a wordpress-based real estate ad client site I have developed a system for sending advertisements via e-mail to subscribed clients.

To avoid sending the same advertisement several times, I have created a flag system that highlights whether the advertisement has already been sent or not.

To register the advertisements sent, I use the ID and in a specific column I go to register the IDs of the advertisements selected with a checkbox, the data is transferred through a javascript function.

Here the jquery section code:

```
    var checkboxVals = $('.listing_multi_id');       // This for id of post(advert) checked
    var email_to = $('#lead_email').val();          // This tell me the email to send. 
    var lead_id = $('#lead_id').val();              // This tell me the col ID in DB of my client
    var already_ID = $('#annunci_inviati').val();   //This tells me which ids are already present in the database row as sent

    var vals = $('.listing_multi_id:checked').map(function() {return this.value;}).get().join(',') // This create array of ids of post(advert) checked


   // And all information is sent through json post 
     $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: {
                        'action': 'houzez_match_listing_email',
                        'ids': vals,
                        'email_to': email_to,
                        'id_lead': lead_id,
                        'already_inviati': already_ID,
                    },''''
```

Here the php section code:

```
            // I have omitted all the information that does not concern the question, the function I am using is much more complex and structured than the one you see

      $listing_ids = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['ids']); // Array with the ids of post

      $already_inviati1 = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['already_inviati']); // Array with the ids of post already sent 


    // Here transform the array in array with INT ids
    $strings_array = explode(',', $already_inviati1);
    
    foreach ($strings_array as $each_number=>$id) {
        $already_inviati2[] = $id;
    } 
    // up to here

   // Here check if the is the first sent or not

     if (isset($already_inviati1)) {
        $merged = array_merge($already_inviati2,$listing_ids);

        $annunci_inviati = maybe_serialize($merged);
    } else
    {$annunci_inviati = maybe_serialize($listing_ids);}

    // Here save the value in database
    
    $id_cliente = $_POST['id_lead']; 

        $data_table= $wpdb->prefix . 'crm_enquiries';
        $data = array(
            'annunci_inviati' => $annunci_inviati 
        );

        $format = array(
            '%s'
        );

        $where = array(
            'lead_id' => $id_cliente
        );

        $where_format = array(
            '%d'
        );

       $wpdb->update( $data_table, $data, $where, $format, $where_format ); 

       // FINE SCRIPT
```

As you can see, the script works if it is the first sending of the mails, so if the column is empty.

On the second send, it goes into error, the array is merged but when I go to check its value it becomes this:

```
// I use a hidden input in html to check ids already sent

<input type="hidden" id="annunci_inviati" value="array (
 0 => 0, // Old IDs are lost by becoming numbers
 1 => 1, // Old IDs are lost by becoming number
 2 => 2, // Old IDs are lost by becoming number
 3 => 0, // Old IDs are lost by becoming number
 4 => 53161, // the new id selected
 5 => 53153, // the new id selected
 6 => 53144, // the new id selected
 )">
```

How can I solve?

Comment: In your PHP, `$listing_ids` appears to be a String not an Array.

Comment: I find this question to be too Unclear because it does not contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge a string with an array. Try the below which ensures the input values are correctly converted to arrays.

```php
/**
 * @var array Array of listing ID's.
 */
$listing_ids = !empty( $_REQUEST[ 'ids' ] ) ? array_map( 'intval', explode( ',', $_REQUEST[ 'ids' ] ) ) : [];

/**
 * @var array Array of ID's for post already sent.
 */
$already_sent = !empty( $_REQUEST[ 'already_inviati' ] ) ? array_map( 'intval', explode( ',', $_REQUEST[ 'already_inviati' ] ) ) : [];

/**
 * @var array Merge the listing ID's and already sent ID's for storing.
 */
$merged = array_unique( array_merge( $listing_ids, $already_sent ) );

/**
 * @var int|null The client record to update.
 */
$id_cliente = !empty( $_POST[ 'id_lead' ] ) ? (int)$_POST[ 'id_lead' ] : null; 

if ( $id_cliente ) {
    $data_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'crm_enquiries';

    $wpdb->update( $data_table, [
        'annunci_inviati' => maybe_serialize( $merged )
    ], [
        'lead_id' => $id_cliente
    ], [
        '%s'
    ], [
        '%d'
    ] ); 
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it always gives me the error 
    "array_merge (): Expected parameter 1 as array, null given"

Would parameter 1 be 
     $ listing_ids =! Empty ($ _POST ['ids'])? array_map ('intval', explode (',', $ _POST ['ids'])): [];